# Javax mail EOFException when loading message headers

Tags: java, exception, jakarta-mail

When calling the getMessageID method I receive the following exception.
Does anyone know what leads to the error?

Code

```
for (Message message : messages) {
    if (message instanceof POP3Message) {
        String messageID = ((POP3Message) message).getMessageID();
        ...
    }
}
```

Exception

```
javax.mail.FolderClosedException: java.io.EOFException: EOF on socket
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Message.loadHeaders(POP3Message.java:651) ~[javax.mail-1.5.5.jar:1.5.5]
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Message.getHeader(POP3Message.java:385) ~[javax.mail-1.5.5.jar:1.5.5]
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.getMessageID(MimeMessage.java:1257) ~[javax.mail-1.5.5.jar:1.5.5]
    at de.service.receive(Service.java:410) ~[nuboclient-e40ba7a.jar:e40ba7a]
```

Version

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: `<groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>` doesn't look like "Jakarta Mail"... Try the [real thing](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.mail/jakarta.mail-api/2.1.1)